# Area of $y=1-2x^2, y=|x|$

Tags: calculus, area

Find the area of the region bounded by the given curves,
$y=1-2x^2$, $y=|x|$

I'm pretty sure i can find the area if i have the upper and lower limit but i'm not sure how to proceed when dealing with an absolute.

Comment: you can use symmetry with respect to the y-axis

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=1-2x^2$ and $g(x)=|x|$. Then the graphs of $f$ and $g$ intersect at $(1/2,1/2)$.

Symmetry with respect to the $y-$ axis gives that they intersect also at $(-1/2,1/2)$.

Hence the area in question is given by

$$ 2 \int_0^{1/2}(f(x)-g(x)) dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Absolute value function, i.e. $f(x) =y= \left| x \right|$ is well explained [here.](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function-absolute-value.html)

So, basically you have to find the intersection points of parabola $y=1-2x^2$ and two lines: $y=x$ and $y=-x$, what is easy to do. Now you will have have the bounds of your area, and will easy proceed with calculation of it:

$$I=\int_{-0.5}^{0}\left( 1 - 2x^2 - \left( x \right) \right)dx + \int_{0}^{0.5}\left( 1-2x^2-x \right)dx \approx 0.58.$$

[image]